# Students find a book with rituals and drawn to another world

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, mystery

The movie is basically about a group of students, I think studying psychology, who finds a book of one of the past professors.

**Some fragments**:

- Basically research said: *do this ritual and they get drawn to another world*.
  However they did this and nothing happened, but when they see a reflection, they see the reflection of this professor who's book they found.
  Each time this happens, they go into his world and repeatedly die or something.
- I remember this was in a college and one of the members was a ballerina who got taken in while she was practicing in the dance room full of mirrors.
- I also remember that this professors research they found, he is the one that pulls them in to his world where he can like imagine whatever he wants. Also his world is really just a house where he lives in and his guests are these people that do the ritual. Eventually they beat him by bringing their current professor in, overwhelming the world with his own. However in the end he stays in that world on his own.

Comment: Hi. Do you remember the approximate year of release? The country\language?

Comment: No idea sorry just suddenly remembered it :/ Could be any time really

Comment: I also remember that this professors research they found, he is the one that pulls them in to his world where he can like imagine whatever he wants. also his world is really just a house where he lives in and his guests are these people that do the ritual. eventually they beat him by bringing their current professor in, overwhelming the world with his own. however in the end he stays in that world on his own

Comment: not much to go off sorry just random plots in my head

Comment: @Jerry added your comment to the question so people notice it quicker

Comment: You just suddenly remembered it... but you could surely think... "oh, it was at least ___ years ago that I saw it"... right? Even that would help restrict it to movies that came out earlier than ___ years ago.

Comment: I saw it around a year ago but that doesn't specify the release of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an episode from [Constantine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3489184/?ref_=tt_ov_inf). Episode 11 [A Whole World Out There](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4181442/?ref_=ttep_ep11)

> Four college students recklessly invoke the magic of a mad occultist named Jacob Shaw. When Shaw sucks their consciousnesses into an alternate realm ruled by him to keep as pets, only John Constantine and their professor, Ritchie Simpson, can save them.

More details from [this](http://www.superherohype.com/features/328495-recap-constantine-episode-11-a-whole-world-out-there#/slide/1)

> Miranda, upset by Carter’s death, goes to the dance room for a little late-night, lights-off ballet practice. The same creepy man appears in the mirror, and Miranda is transferred back to the house where she is impaled by rebar.

and

> John and Richie are still on the dream plane, and Richie decides he wants to stay.

Comment: So... is there anything about a ballerina? Please try to draw whatever connections you can to the description on the question.

Comment: I'm looking for any summary online contains more details that match his description, if I didn't find I'll add what I remember about the episode